# Instrucciones ejecutadas durante un tiempo determinado python

Tags: python, timeout

Me gustaria preguntarles la forma o libreria con la cual, hacer que mi codigo se ejecute durante un periodo de tiempo.

Por ejemplo, que yo le pasara el tiempo por un `input` y luego lo ejecutara durante 20 minutos y despues de ahi que ya no siga.

Creo que la libreria `time` de `python` se podria hacer, pero no encuentro la manera, y si no es posible hacerlo con esa libreria, podrian ser tan amables de ayudarme a encontrar otra?

Ahora mismo estoy utilizando esto:

```
import time

stop = int(input('stop: '))
contador = 0

while True:
    print(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    contador +=1
    
    if contador == stop:
        break
```

Pero es un apaño para salir del apuro

Gracias de antemano!.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides básicamente es controlar una ejecución con un *timeout*. Se puede hacer de varias formas, como usar multihilos o subprocesos, aunque dependerá un poco de la exactitud. Quizás lo más sencillo sea usar [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio.html), como ejemplo:

```py
import asyncio

async def tarea_larga():
    # Tarea que tarda 1 hora
    await asyncio.sleep(60*60)
    print('¡Se acabó!')

async def main():
    # Corta la ejecución en 20 minutos
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(tarea_larga(), timeout=20*60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout!')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su aportacion, con un par de ajustes a su codigo, he hecho que funcionara, se lo agradezco!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido útil. Si crees que tus cambios puedan ser de interés para más gente, te animo a añadirlos a tu pregunta.